# drawing a rectangle without clearing the canvas? (eventlisteners?)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm fairly new to javascript. I'm trying to make it possible for users to draw their own objects, and I found a script online that has a pencil and a rectangle tool. Every time you move the mouse when you're using the rectangle tool, the canvas is cleared.

I tried to solve this problem by adding a second canvas on top of the first, but it's not working and I honestly don't know why.

here is my current version of the script: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Scilens/mACuK/

I thought adding event listeners for canvas2 would help, but apparently this:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
canvas2.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
canvas2.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
canvas2.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
```

is not the right way to do that? is that the problem? and how else would I do it? = /
I've been struggling with this for quite a while now, so I'd be glad if you could help me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use a temporary drawing canvas to overlay your permanent canvas**

The general procedure is:

- Create your “permanent” canvas that holds your completed drawings
- Create a “temporary” canvas that the user can do new drawings on (eraseable)
- Initially, use CSS to move the temp canvas off-screen
- When the user presses the mouse down, use CSS to move the temp canvas on top of the permanent canvas
- When the user drags to draw (mousemove), draw on the temporary canvas
- When the user releases the mouse (mouseup), draw that final rectangle on the permanent canvas
- And also move the temp canvas back off-screen

**Mousedown:**

- Save the starting mouse position (==x,y of context.rect)
- Move the temp canvas on top of the permanent canvas
- Set the isDown flag indicating that drawing has started

  ```
  function handleMouseDown(e){
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    // Put your mousedown stuff here
    startX=mouseX;
    startY=mouseY;
    ctx2.clearRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);
    $("#canvas2").css({ left:0, top:0 });
    isDown=true;
  }
  ```

**Mousemove:**

- Clear the temp canvas (the permanent canvas is not erased)
- Draw the rect on the temporary canvas from the starting XY to the current mouse position

  ```
  function handleMouseMove(e){
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    // Put your mousemove stuff here
    ctx2.clearRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);
    drawRect(mouseX,mouseY,ctx2);

  }
  ```

**Mouseup:**

- Move the temp canvas back off-screen
- Draw the user’s final rect on the permanent canvas
- Clear the isDown flag since drawing is complete

  ```
  function handleMouseUp(e){
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    // Put your mouseup stuff here
    isDown=false;
    $("#canvas2").css({ left:-500, top:0 });
    drawRect(mouseX,mouseY,ctx);
  }
  ```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/puk8A/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #wrapper{
        position:relative;
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
    }
    #canvas{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:1px solid green;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #canvas2{
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
        border:3px solid red;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var ctx2=canvas2.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var startX;
    var startY;
    var isDown=false;

    $("#canvas2").css({ left:-500, top:0 });

    function drawRect(toX,toY,context){
        context.beginPath();
        context.rect(startX,startY,toX-startX,toY-startY);
        context.stroke();
    }


    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      startX=mouseX;
      startY=mouseY;
      ctx2.clearRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);
      $("#canvas2").css({ left:0, top:0 });
      isDown=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isDown=false;
      $("#canvas2").css({ left:-500, top:0 });
      drawRect(mouseX,mouseY,ctx);
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isDown=false;
      $("#canvas2").css({ left:-500, top:0 });
      drawRect(mouseX,mouseY,ctx);

    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      ctx2.clearRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);
      drawRect(mouseX,mouseY,ctx2);

    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Drag to draw a rect</p>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <canvas id="canvas2" width=300 height=200></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much! that worked = ) and sorry for not replying earlier, I got too excited and carried away with the project ^^